# error when trying to move the first byte from a string into a register

Tags: assembly, masm, masm32, ollydbg

I'm pretty new at masm and I need to make a pocket calculator.
I have done the macros for +, -, /, * and i'm putting my expression in the EBX register.

for example: I type "1 + 2 =" and the EBX takes all that string and stores it.

I'm trying to take every character and store it in CL so that I can call the macro after that. 
I have found the expression 
     **mov cl, byte ptr[ebx]**

But right here my program crashes. I have no idea what's wrong.
Here is my code:

```
    zecimal read:
push offset expr
push offset expr_format
call scanf
add esp,8

mov al,output
mov bl,change ;to change the base ex. Zecimal - Z, Hexa - H
mov ecx,expr

cmp al,cl
jz end      ;if input = "exit"

cmp bl,cl
jz read_loop            ;changes base if = "num"

mov ebx,0       ;reset ebx
mov ecx,0       ;reset ecx

mov ebx,expr        ;replace expr in ebx
mov eax,0           ;reset eax

alloc:
mov ecx,0
```

**mov cl,byte ptr[ebx]** ;read 1st char from the string  <--- THIS IS MY PROBLEM

```
    cmp cl,' '      ;comp with spce
jz space        

mul ten
sub cl,'0'
add ax,cx
inc ebx
jmp alloc

space: <-- this is where i compare the sign with my operators
    .....
```

I have searched everywhere and found nothing. PLEASE HELP :(

Comment: It's been a while for me, but how about doing `mov ebx,offset expr` instead of `mov ebx,expr`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `alloc` loop you're reading from `[ebx]`, and right before the start of the loop you set `ebx` to `expr`. You haven't shown the declaration of `expr` or explained what it's supposed to be, but I'm going to guess that it's an array of bytes that you use to hold a string. In that case, the line `mov ebx, expr` should be `mov ebx, offset expr`